# Retrieve Results from NUnit Programmatically

Tags: unit-testing, c#-4.0, automation, nunit

Is it possible to retrieve the results of the Unit tests run using NUnit programmatically? If Yes then How? I have read that we can generate XML file using Nunit Console. Is there any other way around apart from generating and then parsing XML?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. You can use current test context to get name of test, status, working directory, etc

```
[TearDown]
public void TearDown()
{
    var context = TestContext.CurrentContext;
    // context.Test.Name
    // context.Result.Status
}
```

Comment: What if we have more than one tests? How do we get info for all the test methods within that class? Can you suggest some material to read to leans this better?

Comment: I need the test result as pass or failed, the any error message that is generated during test execution or when it fails and if possible the name of class containing test and run duration of each test.

Comment: @user2991609 I suggest you to create base fixture class for your tests, which will have virtual setup and teardown methods. That will allow you to calculate execution time and get data of context. Currently it's not clear how you are going to use this data - write to file or what? So, more info would be good

Comment: I want information in some file, xml or txt or an html will work just fine for me. I need to store information for all the tests.Consider about 200 tests.