# Is there a way to get a list of test results with NUnit?

Tags: c#, report, nunit, teardown

As part of a test project, where I am working on creating an external report at the end to summarize the test results.

I know I can get the Test Context `TestContext.CurrentContext` which has the `Test.Name` and `Result.State`. But in order for this to work in every `TearDown` I would need to call a method to get the `CurrentContext`. I don't like this approach for a few reasons:

1. I would have to call a method to write to the report after each test, it would be much more effecient to write all data at once.
2. Ignored tests don't have a `TearDown`, and ignored tests are very important in this report.
3. *Theoretically* the test can ***STILL*** fail in the `TearDown`, and if it does, it would never reach the method to add it's result to the report.

I am looking for a way, after all the tests are complete, to get a list of them along with their results so that I can use that data to output into my report. Any pointers are greatly appreciated!

Comment: I am using Visual Studio 2012's built in runner, but it would need to work with VS 2013, 2015, as well as ReSharpers runner.

Comment: Does [Logging test results with NUnit](http://jimmykeen.net/2015/02/28/logging-test-results-with-nunit/) help?

Comment: @stuartd If there is some way to retrieve that those logs programatically, possibly

Comment: That sample logs the test results to a file, which you could read in and parse..? (The unanswered question is whether Ignored tests are logged..)

Comment: The link also notes that [it's all different for NUnit3](https://github.com/nunit/dev/wiki/Addins)

Comment: The sample with it's Addin is definitely the way to go for all the reasons listed by @James_Madison plus this overriding one: It's not the job of your tests to log tests - it's the job of some kind of test logger object, which your tests should not need to know about. In NUnit 3.0, we have engine extension points and just added one for handling test events. Converting the sample to a TestEventListener extension would be pretty easy. In 3.0, you would get ignored tests, in 2.x you might not, although you would see tests that "started" but never ended.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Retrieve Results from NUnit Programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20852827/retrieve-results-from-nunit-programmatically)